# Karma testing a directive says angular.element has no method 'hide'

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs-directive, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm trying to setup Karma to test an angular app that I'm building. I've already setup testing around my services and controllers but am finding directives somewhat more complicated to test.

The directive:

```
angular.module('Directives',[])
  .directive('tooltip', function factory(){
    return {
      link: {
        post: function(scope, $element, instanceAttrs, controller){

          $element.parent().append('<span class="tooltip-wrapper"><aside class="tooltip-container"></aside></span>');

          var $tooltipWrapper = $element.next()
            , $tooltip        = angular.element($tooltipWrapper.children()[0]);

          if(instanceAttrs.icon){
            $tooltipWrapper.addClass('help icon standalone');
            $element = $tooltipWrapper;
          }

          if(instanceAttrs.position){
            $tooltip.addClass('tooltip-position-' + instanceAttrs.position);
          } else {
            $tooltip.addClass('tooltip-position-bottom-center');
          }

          if(instanceAttrs.position === 'right'){
            $tooltipWrapper.addClass('tooltip-wrapper-right');
          }

          if(typeof instanceAttrs.message === 'undefined'){

            $tooltip.html(instanceAttrs.$$element[0].childNodes[0].data);
            $element.parent().children('tooltip').remove();
          }
          else {
            $tooltip.html(instanceAttrs.message);
          }

          $tooltip.hide();  // <--- this is where the error gets thrown
          $element.on('mouseover', goTooltip);

          function goTooltip(){
            $tooltip.show();
            $element.on('mouseleave', killTooltip);
            $element.off('mouseover');
          }
          function killTooltip(){
            $tooltip.hide();
            $element.off('mouseleave');
            $element.on('mouseover', goTooltip);
          }
        }
      },

      scope: false,
      replace: false,
      restrict:'EA'
    };
  });
```

The test:

```
describe("The tooltip", function(){

  var elm
    , scope;

  beforeEach(module("RPMDirectives"));

  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $compile){

    elm = angular.element(
      '<div>' +
        '<a></a>' +
        '<tooltip icon="true" position="bottom-center-left">bar</tooltip>' +
      '</div>' );

    scope = $rootScope;
    $compile(elm)(scope);
    scope.$digest();
  }));

  it('should do something', inject(function($compile, $rootScope){
    expect(elm.find('aside')).toBe('bar');
  }))
});
```

When I run the test it says that Object [object Object] ($tooltip, indicated by the comment in the directive) has no method hide. The directive works fine when I use it in my browser, and jqlite definitely has a hide method, so I'm at a loss. I'm sure I could get it to work by including jquery in the testing environment, but I'd rather not do that as I'm in the process of removing jquery in favor of Angular in our production app, and proving that scenario here is critical.

Comment: I am not seeing a hide method in the latest version of the angular docs. What version of angular are you using?

Comment: That's a really good catch. I was looking at the docs for an older version of angular. Hide works because jquery is included on the page currently. I'll have to refactor the directive to account for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to moral apeman above. It turns out that I was looking at the wrong version of the angular docs and hide is no longer a method of angular.element. Nothing wrong with Jasmine or Karma and testing Angular is still a dream.